# What is the django query to find the records where the searching date is between two columns are not?

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

```
"select * from resource_management 
 where ('2015-11-08' between employee_effective_start_date and
                             employee_effective_end_date )"
```

I want the above sql query to be executed using Django orm(QUERYS)  can anyone please help me how it should be framed in Django.
Is it using annotation!

Thanks for dropping by.

Comment: Where are the relevant part of your models?

Answer (score 0):

No annotations needed. Assuming `employee_effective_start_date` and `employee_effective_end_date` are (date) fields of a `ResourceManagement` model, something as trivial as

```
ResourceManagement.objects.filter(
    employee_effective_start_date__lt='2015-11-08',
    employee_effective_end_date__gt='2015-11-08'
)
```

will work. If you want to be as locale and db independent as possible you can replace `'2015-11-08'` by `'datetime(2015, 11, 8)'`.